# Is there any MPU, MCU or SOC that have SIL certification?

Tags: processor, embedded-systems, microcontroller

Is it possible only a component have a SIL level,

For example is there a processor that have IEC 61508 SIL4 certificate or EN 50126 SIL4 certificate.

If there exists what would you recommend to me for processor.

Comment: Here are the [guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206/10648) for asking questions on Hardware Recommendations. The downvote button says: *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"* -- Your question does not show any research effort; Googling "IEC 61508 CPU" returns all sorts of viable products, why did these search results not satisfy your requirements? What **are** your requirements? You are also asking more than one question which could lead to downvotes for being too broad.

Comment: Thank you sir for clarifying and also thank you for your response. The point here is not only the processor has IEC 61508 compliance it also has SIL4 certification for it. i mean.